sf: Find bounding boxes for groups and comparison with ArcGIS Pro results
I am new to sf and trying to generate bounding boxes (as well as calculate their area) for grouped points in the sf package. I am able to get bounding boxes that appear correct, but am running into issues when trying to plot things. I am also curious about the differences between how bounding boxes are created by st_bbox and ArcGIS Pro's 'Minimum Bounding Geometry' tool.
Question 1) Is there an easier way than my code below to get the grouped bounding boxes? I based it off of: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1179. I also checked out Create polygons representing bounding boxes for subgroups using sf, but that approach did not work for me.
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(units)

# Sim some locations

ID <- rep(seq(1:4),each = 4)
NC <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% filter(FIPS == c("37007", "37123", "37167", "37179")) %>% st_transform(crs = 26917)
points <- st_sample(NC, size = c(4,4), type = "random") %>% st_transform(crs = 26917)
Example <- bind_rows(list(geometry = points))
Example$ID <- ID
Example <- st_as_sf(Example, crs = 26917)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = NC) + geom_sf(data = Example, aes(color = ID))
st_write(Example, "Example.csv", layer_options = "GEOMETRY=AS_XY") # For export to compare to ArcPro
Example2 <- Example # We'll use this later

# Find bounding box by group. Pulled the function and process from https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1179

st_bbox_by_feature = function(x) {
  x = st_geometry(x)
  f <- function(y) st_as_sfc(st_bbox(y))
  do.call("c", lapply(x, f))
}

# This works up to the point where I try to map it

Example <- Example %>% dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::summarise() %>% st_cast("MULTIPOINT") # Convert this to a multipoint geometry
Example.BoundBox <- st_bbox_by_feature(Example)
Example$BoundBox <- st_cast(Example.BoundBox, "MULTIPOLYGON",
                            ids = Example$ID,
                            group_or_split = TRUE)
Example$BoundBox_Area <- st_area(Example.BoundBox)
Example.BoundBox <- st_as_sf(Example.BoundBox, crs = 26917)
Example <- st_transform(Example, crs = 26917)

Map1 <- ggplot() +  geom_sf(data = Example.BoundBox) + geom_sf(data = Example, aes(color = ID)) 
Map1

Map2 <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = Example, aes(color = ID)) 
Map2

Map3 <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = Example.BoundBox) 
Map3

I can make Map3, but I get the following error trying to map the original points (Map1 or Map2): Error in st_transform.sfc(X[[i]], ...) :
cannot transform sfc object with missing crs.
But when I check the CRS and active geometry of the original points, it returns the correct CRS and says the MULTIPOINT geometry is active.
st_geometry(Example) 
st_crs(Example)
st_geometry(Example.BoundBox)

Question 2) Why does geom_sf think I don't have a CRS set in my approach above?
Question 3) I can get things to work and map properly using the approach below where I never append the bounding box to my original Example data frame. The problem here, however, is that the Example.BoundBox variable loses the column that has the group ID. Is there a way to keep that ID during my process so I can color the bounding boxes and original points by ID?
Example2 <- Example.ORIGINAL 
Example2 <- Example2 %>% dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::summarise() %>% st_cast("MULTIPOINT") # Convert this to a multipoint geometry
Example2.BoundBox <- st_bbox_by_feature(Example2)
Example2$BoundBox_Area <- st_area(Example2.BoundBox)
Example2.BoundBox <- st_as_sf(Example2.BoundBox, crs = 26917)
st_geometry(Example2)
st_geometry(Example2.BoundBox) 

Map4 <- ggplot() +  geom_sf(data = Example2.BoundBox) + geom_sf(data = Example2, aes(color = ID)) 
Map4

Question 4) When I convert the XY data to points in ArcPro and use the 'Minimum Bounding Geometry" tool, it's clear that st_bbox and ArcPro have different processes for determining these bounding boxes (pictures attached). I think the ArcPro approach is better for my interests, is there a setting in st_bbox I can use to mirror this?
Bounding Boxes made by ArcPro
Bounding Boxes made by sf

I think this is an interesting question that will have a solution. However, there needs to be one question per post and yours currently has the appearance of multiple questions. As such, other users may vote to close your question  In essence though, you have a single question: "How to replicate the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool from ArcPro for groups of sf points". Please consider editing your question down to something like "this is what I tried", then "this is the result but ID and CRS are lost, and it's not the same as the ArcPro result".

crs is an attribute of sfc (geometry column), for sf object it's the crs of active geometry column, but other geometry columns might have a different or missing crs.
And single geometries in sfc do not have a crs attribute, e.g:
st_crs(st_geometry(NC))$Name
#> [1] "NAD83 / UTM zone 17N"
st_crs(st_geometry(NC)[[1]])
#> Coordinate Reference System: NA

So when building bboxes from sfc items as in st_bbox_by_feature(), returned object will not have it either.
Though it is kind of unexpected that that ggplot fails when there's an issue with a geometry column it should not really care about, but apparently it attempts to transform all existing sfc columns.
Modified st_bbox_by_feature() and polygons from st_minimum_rotated_rectangle() :
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

st_bbox_by_feature = function(x) {
  x = st_geometry(x)
  f <- function(y) st_as_sfc(st_bbox(y))
  do.call("c", lapply(x, f)) |> 
    st_set_crs(st_crs(x))
}

set.seed(42)
NC <- 
  read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) |> 
  filter(FIPS %in% c("37007", "37123", "37167", "37179")) |> 
  st_transform(crs = 26917)

Example <- 
  NC[,"geometry"] |> 
  mutate(ID = row_number() |> factor()) |> 
  split(~ID) |> 
  map(\(x) mutate(x, geometry = st_sample(geometry, 4) |> st_union())) |> 
  bind_rows() |> 
  mutate(
    bbox_rect = st_bbox_by_feature(geometry),
    min_rect  = st_minimum_rotated_rectangle(geometry)
  )
Example
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
#> Active geometry column: geometry
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 534114.7 ymin: 3852971 xmax: 622364.9 ymax: 3927168
#> Projected CRS: NAD83 / UTM zone 17N
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>                                         geometry ID                    bbox_rect
#> *                               <MULTIPOINT [m]> <fct>             <POLYGON [m]>
#> 1 ((589272.7 3917694), (601535.2 3927168), (607… 1     ((589272.7 3894158, 6223…
#> 2 ((561263.4 3907589), (564217.7 3925598), (568… 2     ((561263.4 3895442, 5837…
#> 3 ((534114.7 3871532), (534554.2 3861650), (552… 3     ((534114.7 3852971, 5562…
#> 4 ((578869.2 3886585), (580300.2 3879335), (599… 4     ((578869.2 3866860, 6029…
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: min_rect <POLYGON [m]>

# check sfc columns
Example |> 
  select(where(\(x) is(x, "sfc"))) |> 
  map(\(geom) st_crs(geom) |> format()) |>
  str()
#> List of 3
#>  $ geometry : chr "NAD83 / UTM zone 17N"
#>  $ bbox_rect: chr "NAD83 / UTM zone 17N"
#>  $ min_rect : chr "NAD83 / UTM zone 17N"

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = NC, alpha = .5) + 
  geom_sf(data = Example, aes(color = ID)) +
  geom_sf(data = Example, aes(geometry = bbox_rect, color = ID), fill = NA, linewidth = .5, alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf(data = Example, aes(geometry = min_rect, fill = ID), alpha = .4) +
  theme_minimal() 


Created on 2024-10-19 with reprex v2.1.1

A simple approach to obtain the desired output is to use st_bbox with summarise. The main trick is to convert the result of st_bbox to a geometry using st_as_sfc.
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

# Create data
ID <- rep(seq(1:4),each = 4)
NC <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) |>
  filter(FIPS == c("37007", "37123", "37167", "37179")) |> 
  st_transform(crs = 26917)
points <- st_sample(NC, size = c(4,4), type = "random") |>
  st_transform(crs = 26917)|>
  # Transform geometry to sf
  st_as_sf() |>
  # Add ID column
  mutate(ID = ID)

# Summarise and convert st_bbox to sfc
resul <- points |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  summarise(geometry = st_bbox(x) |>
              st_as_sfc())

# Plot with tmap
tm_shape(resul) +
  tm_polygons(col = "ID") +
  tm_shape(points) +
  tm_bubbles(col = "ID")


The problem with question 2 and 3 is that you are creating an object with two columns that indicate geometries. Thus, although geometry column of Example seems to hace associated a valid CRS, but not the BoundBox column. You can test this by comparing the Map1 creation using as data Example |> select(BoundBox, ID) and Example |> select(geometry, ID). For Question 4, I don't know.

Ad 1:
I would simplify a bit the workload:
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# Sim some locations

ID <- rep(seq(1:4),each = 4)
NC <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% filter(FIPS == c("37007", "37123", "37167", "37179")) %>% st_transform(crs = 26917)
points <- st_sample(NC, size = c(4,4), type = "random") %>% st_transform(crs = 26917) |>
  sf::st_as_sf()

points$ID <- ID

Now grouping by ID and unioning them with summarize().
p <- points |>
  dplyr::group_by(ID) |>
  dplyr::summarise()

Right now we have sf object with 4 multipoints:
p
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 535698.5 ymin: 3854754 xmax: 598450.8 ymax: 3924689
#> Projected CRS: NAD83 / UTM zone 17N
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>      ID                                                                        x
#>   <int>                                                         <MULTIPOINT [m]>
#> 1     1 ((588143.5 3912533), (588610.2 3922972), (591227.2 3901171), (597819.4 …
#> 2     2 ((558049.3 3912662), (562710.3 3903506), (567616.1 3903883), (571403.6 …
#> 3     3 ((535698.5 3883082), (539581.1 3875671), (539721.5 3870503), (550343.4 …
#> 4     4 ((564855.4 3854754), (575375.1 3872175), (589384.5 3859255), (598450.8 …

Calculating bounding boxes and displaying it with {tmap}:
x <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(p)), function(x) sf::st_as_sfc(sf::st_bbox(p[x, ,])))
polygons <- do.call(rbind, x) |>
    sf::st_as_sfc(crs = sf::st_crs(points)) |>
    sf::st_sf() |>
    dplyr::mutate(ID = dplyr::row_number())

tmap::tm_shape(polygons) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(fill = "ID") +
  tmap::tm_shape(points) +
  tmap::tm_dots(shape = "ID", size = 0.5)


Ad. 2 and 3 - I'm not an expert in ggplot, especially for mapping, personally using {tmap} for maps, therefore can't answer.
Ad. 4. Don't know what Arcgis "Minimum Bounding Geometry" is, because minimum bounding geometry would be convex hull. Please have a look on sf::st_minimum_rotated_rectangle() function.
Created on 2024-10-18 with reprex v2.1.0
